# Does all the Android apps have notification enabled by default

Tags: android, react-native

I’m looking out for a solution in React native to check if notifications is enabled for Android. If not, enable them. I found out a library (React-native-android-permission-library) which works great. But my question here is I find that notification is enabled by default in our app without specifying in Manifest.xml. I did a bit of reading and found Access_Notification_policy is used for notification which is added as part of API level 23 and that has been considered as Normal permission.

My question here
1. Does all Android apps including our app have notification enabled by default. Is this always be the case?
2. Even lot of permissions are considered as normal, still I believe that it’s not enabled by default.
2. In case notifications are enabled by default, I’m not sure if I still need to check if notification is enabled?
3. Also found somewhere that notification is enabled when your device is registered for location. If this is the case, Can I assume that all devices are registered for location by default.

Please advise.